# Xbox 360 boot up problem

Tags: xbox-360

I'm facing a problem that is really annoying me. My Xbox was working fine but now it take a lot of time to boot up.

When I switch it on, its fan works and all lights are green but it takes hell of a time to boot up. I've tried all the solutions I can find, including:

- Changing my hdmi cable
- TV port check with other devices
- Deleting and re-downloading my profile
- Clearing the cache AV port check

Nothing seems to resolve this issue. I would really appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: have you tried booting the 360 without the hard drive in?  What part takes a while to load - the operating system or your profile?

Comment: Are you connecting to a wireless network at all?  I've found that if I have a bad wifi connection it takes forever for my 360 to boot up, initializing the wifi and getting logged in to the network.

Comment: Do two things.  Disconnect your wifi, and remove all storage devices.  If this doesn solve it, contact some one for help.  Other wise....yea

Comment: @Zero Stack, Virusboy,Sous2817 thanx for the replies, im not connecting my xb with wifi, i,ve found few hours back that my xb do take less time to boot up when connected through AV, although the time it takes to boot up even on AV is far longer than normal. And another thing is that, when my xb boots up once, then it take less time to boot up if i turn it off and on again,its like it's hard to leave the bed in the morning. By booting up i ment system boot up, profile loads up just fine once the system boots up. Sometimes it takes even 30 minutes to boot up :(

Comment: It seems to be a known issue on the 360. There is a discussion about it in the xbox.com Forums: http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/7/t/326299.aspx in short they say: more files on console = slower boot up. You should delete files you dont need any longer and clear the system cache. Try this and give me a response

Answer (score 1):

There are several users around who got these kind of "bug" and of course there're several "fixes" out there. I say "fixes" because i wasn't able to find a solution that worked for all users.

[**There's a reddit about this issue**](http://www.reddit.com/r/xbox360/comments/2fwr0b/why_is_my_xbox_360_slim_suddenly_so_slow_to_load/) but i'll give you a little summary of all possibilitys the people on reddit  posted.

> 1. Clear Cache 5 times straight. A tip from support that helped me solve mine last year
>
> to do so Go to settings, storage and press Y.

---

> 2. Press the center button on your controller, go to the far right and choose Profile. Then choose Auto Sign-in and disable it. Turn off the xbox and turn it back on. It starts up in seconds now.
>    Now try to sign in to an account that you don't use that often (if you don't have one, skip this step). Set that one to auto-sign in. Reset xbox, super fast startup...just like the bedroom! Ha!
>    Next, go to your system>storage>hard drive>profiles and choose the profile that you're having the slow startup with. Notice the profile size (mine was 25MB). Click Delete but choose Delete Profile Only. DO NOT DO PROFILE & ITEMS OR YOU'LL LOSE ALL THE DLC CONNECTED TO THE PROFILE! It'll sign you out if you're signed into that account.
>    Back on your dashboard, not signed into any profile, press the xbox button on the controller and choose Download Profile. Redownload your profile and start over. Once mine was downloaded again, it was all the sudden 12MB. Half the size of the old one, cool, but ultimately, half the startup time when that profile is set up for auto signin.

---

> 3. Remove the hard drive, then boot with the hard drive out. Decline the update so it goes to the dashboard. Power off, then insert the drive.

That are all mentioned possible fixes. If you want to know what worked and what not, you've to read the discussion on reddit i've mentioned. I hope any of those will do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanx guys for your concern. @Nitro.de I've tried everything mentioned in readit post prior to posting my question hereand nothing solved the issue, its really painful to wait to play a game :(

Comment: Did you try to clear up the hard drive? Delete things you dont need anymore and See if this has an effect on the boot speed

Comment: I don't really have anything to delet in my HDD,  4 or 5 games all my HDD is holding and i don't keep the games i dont play so my HDD almost have 150 gigs free.@Nitro.de

Comment: hmm then i'm out man sorry

Comment: @Zero Stack i,ve tried to start it up without HDD and it starts fine, i,ve 250 gb hdd. But when i put it back in then it takes much time to boot. I dont have many games in my hdd and its have 150 gigs empty

Comment: so my point 3 dont work "remove hard drive...decline update...power off and insert hard drive again"?